# Exporting an imported module from an internal module in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I would like to export an imported module from an internal module in TypeScript, as below:

```
import MyExternalModule from './my_external_module';

function MyModule() {
  doWork();
}

module MyModule {
  export MyExternalModule;
}

export = MyModule;
```

Obviously, this doesn't work. Is there any valid way of exporting the external module from my module?

Answer (score 0):

The following works :

```
import MyExternalModule from './my_external_module';
export {MyExternalModule};
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not state this in the original question, but I need an actual module there. I have edited my original question to reflect my needs!